# Limit of a function with bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Let $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function whose derivative satisfies $|f'|\leq 1$. Prove that the following limit exists: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow+\infty} f(\frac{1}{n}).$$

I have been trying to prove that the limit of the function in $x=0$ exists, but I do not really know how to go about it. Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Does one need the derivative to exist and be bounded? The function is continuous on a compact domain, so its image is compact. So the limit should exist regardless (?)

Comment: @Imago there is no explicit statement saying that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Thomas the fact that the derivative is bounded implies that $f$ is Lipschitz

Comment: @Tyler6 yes, of course. But Imago has questioned whether the assumption about the derivative is needed.

Comment: @Thomas ah, I misread. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in a comment, the statement is interesting mostly if $f$ is defined only on the open interval $(0,1)$. In that case the mean value theorem applies. So, if $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence converging to $0$, there is $\xi_{n,m}\in (a_n, a_m) $ such that

$$|f(a_n)-f(a_m)|\le |f^\prime(\xi_{n,m})||a_n-a_m|$$

This means (by the assumption on the norm of the derivative) that the left hand side is Cauchy and, therefore, converges.

(Of course this also applies if $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$...)